# Flutter Key type how to make key to be required based on the type?

Tags: flutter

I face some issues on flutter key required as I wanted to create a custom widget with the key required based on the type how can I do this?

```
class CustomTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  CustomTextField(
      {Key? key,
      this.label = "",
      required this.type,
      required this.labelText,
      required this.hintText,
      required this.validationText,
      type = "password" ? required this.validField : this.validField = "",
      this.helpTxt = ""})
      : super(key: key);

  final String label;

  final String labelText;

  final String hintText;

  final String validationText;

  final String validField;

  final String helpTxt;

  final String type;

  @override
  _CustomTextField createState() => _CustomTextField();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ValueKey` to generate different keys on the value you passed as a parameter.
for your case you can give something like this:-

```
class CustomTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  CustomTextField(
      {Key? key,
      this.label = "",
      required this.type,
      required this.labelText,
      required this.hintText,
      required this.validationText,
      type = "password" ? required this.validField : this.validField = "",
      this.helpTxt = ""})
      : super(key: ValueKey(this.type));

  final String label;

  final String labelText;

  final String hintText;

  final String validationText;

  final String validField;

  final String helpTxt;

  final String type;

  @override
  _CustomTextField createState() => _CustomTextField();
}
```